# Curve fitting with SciPy's least_squares()

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm doing least squares curve fitting with Python and getting decent results, but would like it to be a bit more robust.

I have data from a first order LTI system, more specifically the speed of a motor that is read by a tachymeter. I'm trying to fit the step response of the motors so I can deduce its transfer function.

The speed (v(t)) has the following form:
v(t) = K * (1 - exp(-t/T))

I'm having some outliers in the data I use though, and would like to mitigate them. This mostly happens when the speeds becomes constant. Say the speed is 10000 units, I sometimes get outliers that are 10000 +/- 400. I wonder how to set my f_scale parameter given I want my data points to stay within +/- 400 of the "actual" speed (mean). Should I set f_scale to 400 or 800? I'm not sure what exactly I should set there.

Thanks

EDIT: Some data.
[image]

Comment: You will have much more luck if you post code and data so that we can replicate your results before making suggestions.

Comment: I can post a graphic, but my question relates mostly on how f_scale relates to the margin I want to determine what is noise and what is correct data. Is it basically just f_scale=margin, f_scale=margin^2, etc. I'm a bit confused by the docs to be honest.

Comment: The picture is useful, but the actual data would have been better. It is not clear if your error is systematically larger than the "actual" values or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have constructed a minimal example which is for a curve similar to yours. If you had posted actual data instead of a picture, this would have gone a bit faster. The two key things to understand about robust fitting with `least_squares` is that you have to use a different value for the `loss` parameter than linear and that `f_scale` is used as a scaling parameter for the loss function.

Basically, from the docs, `least_squares` tries to

```
minimize F(x) = 0.5 * sum(rho(f_i(x)**2)
```

and setting the loss `loss` parameter changes `rho` in the above formula. For `loss='linear'` `rho` is just the identity function. When `loss='soft_l1'`, `rho(z) = 2 * ((1 + z)**0.5 - 1)`. `f_scale` is used to scale the loss function such that `rho_(f**2) = C**2 * rho(f**2 / C**2)`. So it doesn't have the same kind of meaning as you are asking for above, it's more like a way of penalising larger errors less.

In this particular case it doesn't appear to make much difference though.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

tmax = 6000
N = 100
K = 6000
T = 200

smootht = numpy.linspace(0, tmax, 1000)
tm = numpy.linspace(0, tmax, N)

def f(t, K, T):
    return K * (1 - numpy.exp(-t/T))

v = f(smootht, K, T)

vm = f(tm, K, T) + numpy.random.randn(N)*400

def error(pars):
    K, T = pars
    vp = f(tm, K, T)
    return vm - vp

f_scales = [0.01, 1, 100]

plt.scatter(tm, vm)
for f_scale in f_scales:
    r = scipy.optimize.least_squares(error, [10, 10], loss='soft_l1', f_scale=f_scale)
    vp = f(smootht, *r.x)
    plt.plot(smootht, vp, label=f_scale)
plt.legend()
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: effect of f_scale]

My suggestion is to start by just experimenting with the different loss functions before playing with `f_scale`.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of understand now it's more a parameter to reduce the weight of outliers. While I'm at it, would you know by any chance how I can compute the reduced chi square to determine how good the fit is? Anyhow, thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd suspect that the reason why f_scale doesn't influence the outcome in this case is that the noise in this example is following a symmetric normal distribution anyway, which means that mean==median, and there are no "true outliers" (using the term "outlier" loosely, to mean data that wasn't generated by the well-behaved noise sources you assume but follow a very different trend). With real-world data, that is often not the case, and that's when I'd expect that the choice of loss function and its scale would make a much bigger difference.